# Grails displaying values from two tables using primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql, grails

This is, I hope, probably quite obvious but I can't find an example that I think answers my issue.

I have an SQL database that I cant modify and within it are two tables, linked with primary/foreign keys (test_scenario and test_exec_queue respectively, so the PK value from test_scenario can show up many times within test_exec_queue) and when I display the data on screen I want it to, instead of displaying the FK value from test_exec_queue I want it to use that to get testScenarioName from the test_scenario table and display that instead.

So far my class looks like this but I've no idea what to put in to do the above logic, or do I do this somewhere else?  In the controller?  Any help appreciated

```
class TestExecQueue {

    static constraints = {
        testscenarioid(blank:false, editable:false)
        myPriority(inList:[0,1,2,3,4], blank:false)
        myState(inList:["READY"], blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "test_exec_queue"
        version false
        columns{

            id column:"test_exec_queue_id"
            testscenarioid column:"test_scenario_id"
            myPriority column:"Priority"
            myState column:"State"
        }
    }

    Integer testscenarioid
    Integer myPriority
    String myState
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class which maps the `test_scenario` table in addition to the `TestExecQueue` class you've already implemented.

In your `TestExecQueue` class, you would link to the scenario by class, rather than by an integer field:

```
class TestExecQueue {
    static mapping = {
        scenario column:'test_scenario_id'
    }

    TestScenario scenario
}
```

*Note: This is one example of mapping the relationship, you should review the [Domain Modeling section of the Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#domainClasses) for other options.*

The display of the classes is entirely dependent on your controllers and views, and that would need more elaboration on your part to answer clearly. One option is to set the `public toString()` methods on the classes that will be printed.

Comment: Thanks for that. For display purposes all I want it to do is get the test_scenario_id value from the test_exec_queue table, go to the test_scenario table and look up equivalent test_scenario_id, get the testScenarioName value and display that instead of the value (i.e instead of showing a test_scenario_id value of 2 as its stored in the test_exec_queue table, I want it to show "test 001", which is the testScenarioName value stored in the test_scenario table which has the matching test_scenario_id value, both tables have a field called test_scenario_id).

Comment: So, I've added the stuff as suggested above and somethings working, however my view is now showing "myframework.TestScenario : 1" rather than the actual value, any ideas? :/

Comment: That is the default `toString()` implementation for a GORM domain class. Override it inside `TestScenario` to display the name field that you want.

Comment: AHA!  Excellent!  Cheers, I was putting the toString in the wrong place, wrong end of the stick and all, cheers! :)